# How to Create an Account in Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play

Please any one help to me for

```
how to create an account in Google play store??

how will upload the apk file in Google play store???
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I guess they have a tutorial there. The Google guys normally do these things.

Comment: If you have any Experience please share to me

Comment: @ArunKumar please see my answer below. this is the official google guide. it's easy. i did it too. but remember that you have to pay 25$ the first time and then you can upload your apks. only the first time 25$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please follow steps at this link provided by google (keep inmind that you have to pay 25$ first time to be a google play developer.

[Developer Registration](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113468)